# Difference between "igual" and "como"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

I was listening to Carlos Varela's "Una Palabra" and noticed sometimes he uses "igual" for "like" and sometimes "como".  I am knowing that "igual" is used more similarities, but what separates it from "como"?

Answer (score 1):

"Igual" means "equal", indicating that two things are equal to each other. "Como" means "like", meaning that two things are like each other. "Igual" implies equality, whereas "como" implies similarity. In other words, "igual" is a much stronger word.

Answer (score 1):

You would use 'como' for similes.  For example, [como pan comido](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/111168/similes-in-spanish) or [como un flan](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/111168/similes-in-spanish).  Igual indicates equivalence or sameness.  For example, "yo pienso igual" *(I think the same)* or [Ella habla a Ricardo de igual a igual](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/131778/learn-spanishenglish-phrases-all-levels-both-languages-de-igual-a-igual-) *(She speaks to Richard as an equal)*.  Please see the sites I have linked for more examples and information.

Comment: "como pan comido or como un flan"  :-) provocador. Ella habla a Ricardo de igual a igual. Ella le habla como a un igual. Yo pienso como ella. Hhmm..